# Maven Wagon plugin Post

Tags: maven, maven-wagon-plugin, wagon

I have some xml files and I want to upload them to my domain. Only way i can do it is through endpoint. I have configured maven wagon plugin like below

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <goals>
                    <goal>upload</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <fromDir>target</fromDir>
                    <includes>*jssp.xml</includes>
                    <url> http://mydomain/endpoint?__sessiontoken=admin/admin</url>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

And i have this

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:1.0:upload (default-cli) on project AdobeCampaignUploader: Error handling resource: Access denied to: http://mydomain/endpoint?__sessiontoken=admin/admin/file.xml
```

How to POST this file to remote location properly?

Comment: Did you ever figure out to POST instead of PUT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably missing your authentication here. To ~/.m2/[settings.xml](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers), add your http credentials, then use these [here](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/upload-single-mojo.html#serverId) in your pom.